# Remove a key from a JsValue in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

It's probably a very easy question but I'm having trouble finding a clean/working solution. 
I just want to remove a field from a json object I have. 
Let's say I have :

```
val body:Option[JsValue] = request.body.asJson
```

where body looks like:

```
{
     "url": "www.google.com",
     "id":  "123",
     "count" : 1,
     "label" : "test"  
 }
```

and I want to remove the field "id" from it.

I have read http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonTransformers case#6 but unfortunately couldn't fully understand it. (I'm pretty new to Scala and functional programming)

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This can be done as a `JsObject`, which extends `JsValue`:

```
body.as[JsObject] - "id"
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to do something like this:


    val jsonTransformer = (__ \ 'id).json.prune; 
    val newBody = body.get.transform(jsonTransformer)


But your solution is definitely simpler and better.

Comment: Beautyful, just, beautyful. Keep getting amazed by Scala.

Comment: What if you want to remove a nested field?

Answer (score 5):

I came across this question when I wanted to remove a nested field from a json object, and since subtracting doesn't work for nested fields, I'm adding the solution I ended up using.

To remove a field from a JsObject you can use prune to remove the entire path to that field.

For the example above -

```
val p = JsPath \ "id"
val res = p.prune(body.as[JsObject]).get
```

If you had a nested object like this -

```
{
     "url": "www.google.com",
     "id":  {"first": "123", "second": "456"}
     "count" : 1,
     "label" : "test"  
 }
```

you could create a more specific path -

```
val p = JsPath \ "id" \ "second"
val res = p.prune(body.as[JsObject]).get
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [as Method](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#the-default-body-parser) `as[JsObject]` with minus `-` symbol. Like Below.

```
body.as[JsObject] - "id"
```

**Below has detailed explanation step by step. Let's see with custom object.**

```
val json: JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
      "error" -> JsBoolean(false),
      "result" -> JsNumber(calcResult),
      "message" -> JsString(null)
    ))
```

It can be picked by `as` Method and removed "-" symbol.

```
/* Removing Message Property and keep the value in successResult Variable */
val successResult = json.as[JsObject] - "message"
```

Take a look at [Body Parser](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers) in Scala to know about Choosing an explicit body parser, Combining body parsers and Writing a custom body parser.