# Remove JSON array element in scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, rest, playframework

I have a JSON result like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2202,
        "name": "name one",
        "phone": "+62888888",
        "email": "customer@gmail.com",
        "corporateId": null,
        "corporateName": null,
        "version": 119,
        "signupDate": "2016-01-28T00:00:00+07:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2580,
        "name": "name two",
        "phone": "+628777777",
        "email": "customer2@gmail.com",
        "corporateId": null,
        "corporateName": null,
        "version": 119,
        "signupDate": "2016-01-28T00:00:00+07:00"
    }
]
```

How to remove some element so I have new JSON result like this (remove `corporateId` and `corporateName`):

```
[
    {
        "id": 2202,
        "name": "name one",
        "phone": "+62888888",
        "email": "customer@gmail.com",
        "version": 119,
        "signupDate": "2016-01-28T00:00:00+07:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2580,
        "name": "name two",
        "phone": "+628777777",
        "email": "customer2@gmail.com",
        "version": 119,
        "signupDate": "2016-01-28T00:00:00+07:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a key from a JsValue in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066066/remove-a-key-from-a-jsvalue-in-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some ways. One of them [JSON transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#json-transformers).

For removing `corporateId` and `corporateName` use [Case 6: Prune a branch from input JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#Case-6:-Prune-a-branch-from-input-JSON):

```
(__ \ "corporateId").json.prune andThen (__ \ "corporateName").json.prune
```

For removing in every JsArray element, use `Reads.list`:

```
Reads.list(
  (__ \ "corporateId").json.prune andThen (__ \ "corporateName").json.prune
)
```

Complex transformer for you will be:

```
json.transform(
  Reads.list(
    (__ \ "corporateId").json.prune andThen (__ \ "corporateName").json.prune
  ).map(JsArray)
)

res3: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsArray] = JsSuccess([{"id":2202,"name":"name one","phone":"+62888888","email":"customer@gmail.com","version":119,"signupDate":"2016-01-28T00:00:00+07:00"},{"id":2580,"name":"name two","phone":"+628777777","email":"customer2@gmail.com","version":119,"signupDate":"2016-01-28T00:00:00+07:00"}],)
```